# Disable XML caching in perl script

Tags: xml, perl, caching

I am writing a perl script and using XML::Simple to read a XML file. The problem is that my script automatically caches the XML file. Whenever I make any changes in XML file it does not reflect in perl script. I wish to turn off caching. How can I do it?

```
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use DateTime;
use Time::localtime;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("ccl_crawl_config.xml");
```

Comment: There's no caching. Every time you do `XMLin`, it reads the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and found out, that XML::Simple stores the cached file automaticly. So it has nothing to do with your script in particular.

Look in [CPAN description of XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm#Cache_=%3E_%5B_cache_schemes_%5D_#_in_-_advanced).

The options are "storable", "memshare" and "memcopy", but none for cache-ignore.
I would be thankfull, if someone could solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long running program and you would like to reread config file time to time, then you could check the file mod timestamp or you could watch signals (HUP).

The exact details depends on your programm, so if you share more details then I could help more.